# How to hide BottomNavigation bar(Botton Navigation Bar Activity) in specific Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know I am not the first to ask this question but I have referred many SO post regarding this but nothing is solved my query .

What I want to do is in my MainActivity(Bottom Navigation bar Activity) I have Bottom Navigation Bar, In this MainActivity I have cardviews If I clicked on the cardview I need to show another fragment in that fragment I want to hide the bottom navigation bar .And When I nav back to MainActivity botoom Navigation bar should be there.

Here in my case Alarm.java is the fragment where I want to hide the bottom navigation bar.

Alarm.java

```
public class Alarm extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Alarm() {

    }

    public static Alarm newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Alarm fragment = new Alarm();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you've tried thus far, so people don't recommend things you've already tried? For instance, did using the `setSystemUiVisibility` method in your fragment not work?

Answer (score 3):

In your `MainActivity` you can implement two methods that will be responsible for showing and hiding your `BottomNavigationView`. For example, these two methods animate it sliding up and down:

```
private void hideBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
    view.clearAnimation();
    view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight()).setDuration(300);
}

public void showBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
    view.clearAnimation();
    view.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(300);
}
```

In `MainActivity` you call `hide` right before opening your `CardView`, and call `show` in `onCreate` or `onResume`.

**EDIT:**

But, I think that a cleaner way would probably be to create an interface in your Fragment:

```
public interface OnCardViewOpenedInterface{
    void onOpen(); // hide bottom bar when photo is opened
    void onClose(); // show bottom bar when photo is opened
}
```

And call these methods in `onStop` and `onResume` of your `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mListener.onClose();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mListener.onOpen();
}
```

And then implement the interface in your `MainActivity`, override the methods `onOpen()` and `onClose()` and inside call your `hide` and `show` methods.

They will probably both work, maybe the second one is overcomplicated, it's just I like it more.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the method by @Suleyman but it didn't work for me. The simplest solution is to use a `public static` method in the `MainActivity` and reference it from the fragment where you want to hide the bottom navigation bar.

Don't forget to initialize `navView` as `public static`.

In your `MainActivity`

```
    public static void hideBottomNav(){
        navView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public static void showBottomNav(){
        navView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

In your `MyFragment`

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MainActivity.hideBottomNav();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        MainActivity.showBottomNav();
    }
```

Comment: Using a public static property is not a good practice though and it does not seem justified for this usecase.

Comment: Yes but seems to work none the less and easy to implement.

Comment: But there is no animation.